# .NET Razor page being mangled when trying to use JavaScript window.print()

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this razor page in my .NET application (it isn't pretty but it's what the client wanted because it looks like the reports they have been using for years)

[image: Razor Page]

However when the user clicks print it looks like this:

[image: page when printing]

As you can see, a lot of my columns are being pushed to the side of the page or rearranged for some reason. Now I'm not really a front end developer so I assume I've made some mistake when creating this page. What exactly can I do to fix this and why is it happening in the first place?

#### Details page

```
@model Roadway_History.Models.Statewide

<!--            CUSTOM CSS          -->
<link href="~/Styles/Documents/DetailsStyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--            GOOGLE ICONS          -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<div class="container-fluid text-center topLabel">
    <div class="borderline">
        <h4 class="title"><strong>DETAIL RECORD - RP ROADWAY HISTORY FILE</strong></h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <input class="text-left" type="button" onclick="javascript:window.print()" value="Print" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <p class="text-right">
                    <u>Current Date:</u>
                    <script>document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString());</script>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
            <h5><strong>COUNTY:</strong> <span class="box-shadow px-3">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.COUNTY)</span></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
            <h5><strong>District:</strong>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.District)</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
            <h5><strong>Route No:</strong><span class="box-shadow px-4">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RouteNo)</span></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h5><strong>Sign System:</strong><span class="box-shadow px-4">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SignSys)</span></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-left">
            <h5><strong>LocalName:</strong></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
            <h5 class="box-shadow px-3">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LocalName)</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
            <h5><strong>Supp Des:</strong></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
            <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SuppDes)</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
            <h5><strong>Method:</strong></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
            <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Method)</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Duplicate_OK)
            <label class="form-check-label" for="duplicateCheck"><strong>Duplicate OK</strong></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
            <h5><strong>Date:</strong></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
            <h5>What date??</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
            <h5><strong>Original Location:</strong></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
            <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OriginalL)</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
            <h5><strong>Original D:</strong></h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
            <h6>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OriginalD)</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="borderline text-left">
        <h5 class="mb-0"><strong>DOCUMENTS</strong></h5>
    </div>
    <h6 class="text-left">TABLE GOES HERE</h6>
    <div class="borderline text-left">
        <h5 class="mb-0"><strong>PROJECTS</strong></h5>
    </div>
    <h6 class="text-left">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Projects)</h6>
    <div class="borderline text-left">
        <h5 class="mb-0"><strong>COMMENTS</strong></h5>
    </div>
    <h6 class="text-left">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Comments)</h6>
</div>

<p style="margin-top: 20px">
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

#### DetailsStyle.css

```
.topLabel {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.borderline {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px
}

.box-shadow {
    margin-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0.15rem 0.15rem 0.25rem #000000;
}
```

Comment: Have you styled for media print? [print media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Paged_Media)

Comment: I did not know this was a thing. Will look into it now, thank you!

Comment: Try to add css into `@@media{}`,and check what is your layout,Landscape or Portrait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all CSS is able to be printed. Typically what I have done is have a normal version and then, @media print {} version so that I can refine how it will look when getting printed. For example, things like buttons should need to be visible during printing.

Comment: I was not aware of this. Looking into print media now, thank you!

Comment: Could you point me to a resource that might help with what I need specifically? It looks like what is happening is my columns are being pushed left or right.

Comment: I'm personally a fan of CSS tricks: https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/
Hope this helps